# Flask routing multiple optional parameters using url_for()

Tags: flask

I know there are similar questions on this but they don't seem to fit my case outlined below:

I use one optional parameter in many of my routes like this.

```
@bp.route('/page1', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@bp.route('/page1/<foo>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def page1(foo=None):
    if foo:
        # do foo stuff
```

This is called with **url_for('page1')** or **url_for('page1', foo=3)** and it works just fine.

I would like to optionally use additional parameters  like this:

**url_for('page2', foo=4)** or **url_for('page2', bar= 5)** or **url_for('page2', foo=4, bar=5)**

I tried this.

```
@bp.route('/page2', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@bp.route('/page2/<foo>/<bar>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def page1(foo=None, bar=None):
    if foo:
        # do foo stuff
    
    if bar:
        #do bar stuff
```

I was hoping that url_for() would be smart enough to build the request in the correct order if a parameter was missing  since they are known and named  - but it does not. Perhaps empty slot like page2//5 is just not allowed.

Further, **url_for('page2', foo=None, bar= 5)** seems to be illegal ( pycharm will not run it)
and  **url_for('page2', foo='', bar= 5)** will cause a runtime error.

The only thing that does work is **url_for('page2', foo='ignorestring', bar= 5)**

So, I can make this work but have to populate my unused variable(s) with something (instead of None or empty string) which makes for ugly code!

Any ideas how to do this cleanly without resorting to less secure querystrings?

Comment: how about You make another `route` decorator that takes in the other argument?

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at here. If you mean adding @bp.route('/page2/<foo>' and @bp.route('/page2/<bar>'  it won't work because it has no idea if the data is foo data or bar data because the signature is the same

Comment: right, I didn't think about it, however I just thought that You could always use sth else and that is if statements (or for larger scales dictionaries) and then handle conditions that way, otherwise I have no idea how to make it work that way, maybe look at the docs or sth, I am quite new to this

Comment: @Bill could you add expected route when `foo is None` or `bar is None`?

Comment: No None is apparently not allowed by url_for. From declaration:     Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended
    to the generated URL as query arguments.  If the value of a query argument
    is ``None``, the whole pair is skipped.

Comment: @Bill I understand. what is the main problem?

Comment: After a little more research it appears I can make my workaround work cleanly if I can do the following: 1. Override url_for() to change somearg=None to somearg='none'. 2. Create a custom converter that changes somearg = 'none' back to None . My first attempt at custom converter failed - perhaps because I am using Blueprints so I am not sure how far I want to go down this rabbit hole vs living with ugly code.

Comment: 'What is the main problem?' Multiple variable routing seems unnecessarily fragile in that if I pass in bar=55 but not foo then bar is read as foo and if I set foo=none then Flask instead outputs a querystring so anyone can see that I am passing  a bar value (?bar=55)

Comment: @Bill just thought about overriding `url_for()` . looks like you found solution )